# Fastest or most robust way to output posts from a specific category in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to output each of the posts of a specific category on my Wordpress 'Promotions' page, at the moment I'm using the following code below but realise that this might not be the most performant way to perform this process and was wondering if anyone can offer a better solution?

**PHP**

```
<?php
            query_posts('cat=Promotions');
            while (have_posts()) : the_post();
            the_content();
            endwhile;
        ?>
```

**Ok so my latest attempt is:**

```
<?php
            $catquery = new WP_Query( 'category_name=Promotions' );
            while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
            ?>

            <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to query the category by name if you're on the archive page of that category.

for instance if you're trying to call these posts on example.com/category/promotions/ then just have a standard loop in your category.php file and it should work fine. It would look like this:

```
<?php 
   if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) :
         the_post();
         the_content();
      endwhile;
   endif; 
?>
```

However if you're trying to call this loop from some other page then you would have to override the current query using query_posts, as you have already done. Then you'd want to reset the query like so:

```
<?php
   query_posts('cat=Promotions');

   if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) :
         the_post();
         the_content();
      endwhile;
   endif;

   wp_reset_query();
?>
```

either way you go, there isn't really a 'faster' way to do it, this is the way wordpress wants you to use.